# Why is $x^{-1}$ in $H$ whenever $x$ is in $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The following theorem and proof is from Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*

> *Theorem*. Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a nonempty subset of $G$. Then, $H$ is a subgroup of
> $G$ if $ab^{-1}$ is in $H$ whenever $a$ and $b$ are in $H$.
>
> *proof*. Since the operation of $H$ is the same as that of $G$, it is clear that this operation is associative. Next, we show that $e$ is in $H$. Since $H$ is nonempty we may pick some $x$ in $H$. Then, letting $a=x$ and $b=x$ in the hypothesis, we have $e=xx^{-1}=ab^{-1}$ is in $H$. To verify that $x^{-1}$ is in $H$ whenever $x$ is in $H$, all we need to do is to choose $a=e$ and $b=x$ in the statement of the theorem.

When verifying that $x^{-1}$ is in $H$, it feels as if the argument is circular; we haven't really proved that $H$ is in fact, a subgroup. So how can we set $a=e$ and $b=x$, and then say that $x^{-1}$ is in $H$? I was wondering if someone could shed some light.

Comment: Note that the condition is $b \in H$ and not $b^{-1}\in H$ so in the part which proves that $e\in H$ you are only using $x\in H$ and not $x^{-1}\in H$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not circular.

**First** you prove $H$ contains the identity, because it's given nonempty.

**Then** you can use that fact to show $H$ contains the inverse of anything in it.

You're not quite finished. You still have to prove $H$ is closed under multiplication. Can you do that now?

Comment: Suppose $x,z$ are $\in H$. So, for $a=x$ and $b=z^{-1}$ $\in H$ (since, we proved that any $z$ in $H$ has an inverse in $H$), $xz=x(z^{-1})^{-1}=ab^{-1} \in H$. Thus, $H$ is closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Take $a=e$ and $b=x$. Then, $ab^{-1}\in H$ by assumption, but $ab^{-1}=ex^{-1}=x^{-1}$.